# Graph loops in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was under the impression that tensorflow graphs where directed acyclic graphs. However, while exploring the (rather large) graph generated by https://github.com/nilboy/tensorflow-yolo I stumbled on a loop in the graph:

```
 1. gradients/b_count_62:0 -> gradients/b_count_62
 2. gradients/b_count_62 -> gradients/GreaterEqual_15:0
 3. gradients/GreaterEqual_15:0 -> gradients/GreaterEqual_15
 4. gradients/GreaterEqual_15 -> gradients/Merge_31:0, gradients/GreaterEqual_15/Enter:0
 5. gradients/Merge_31:0 -> gradients/Merge_31
 6. gradients/Merge_31 -> gradients/b_count_61:0, gradients/NextIteration_31:0
 7. gradients/NextIteration_31:0 -> gradients/NextIteration_31
 8. gradients/NextIteration_31 -> gradients/Sub_15:0
 9. gradients/Sub_15:0 -> gradients/Sub_15
10. gradients/Sub_15 -> gradients/Switch_31:1, gradients/GreaterEqual_15/Enter:0
11. gradients/Switch_31:1 -> gradients/Switch_31
12. gradients/Switch_31 -> gradients/Merge_31:0, gradients/b_count_62:0 (loop, references line 5 and line 1)
```

What ops support loops like the above, how are these loops created (from python), and what are the semantics of such loops when run in a session?

Answer (score 1):

They are created by `tf.while_loop`, semantics follow the classical Data Flow primitives for distributed while loops, section 3.4 of "TensorFlow: A system for large-scale machine learning" ([link](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/osdi16/osdi16-abadi.pdf)) has some references

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't specific enough - I'd like to create each of these ops directly / separately from python. This seems largely undocumented, but supported by the following methods:

    op._add_input(tensor, dtype=None)
    op._update_input(index, tensor, dtype=None)
    op._add_control_input(ops)

I've tried to read the source code for tf.while_loop, but it's rather complicated and I't snot obvious to me how it uses these (or something else) to generate the dependency loop in the graph.

Comment: Those are "hidden" ops and undocumented on purpose (anything undocumented is not part of API and can be changed/removed at any time), so reading the source code is probably the best way. It seems tf.while_loop is on way to getting deprecated, ie, see this [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/0fd2a74120b86972441378f79fb5d03e86fed856) for replacement. `NextIteration` ops will probably remain but will need lower level API to construct them.

Comment: PS, here's a simpler example of constructing merge/switch nodes directly in order to implement lazy execution of parts of some graph -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/d67410e240369736fc4ba0267250ef27